# Change Layout seek barfrom service class in android

Tags: android

i have service class called `mediaPlayerService` in my android project.
and i'm handling all play, pause, next, previous commands from service. by sending broadcast messages to the service,
but in my player's `layout.xlm` has seekbar to display current state of the song. How can i update that from `service` . because my `activity.kt` dont have any data about playing song. it only start service and sending commands to service.

**so how to etit my `Seekbar` in `layout.xml` by the service**?

Comment: you can do that with the helop runOnUIThread

Comment: i didn't understand that

Comment: if you have activity reference inside service then you can invoke runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {} method to update your ui from service other wise you can use braodcast receiver to send broadcast from service to activity to update textview

Comment: it is not only textView i need to update the seek bar too. how to do it . i cant use broadcast messages to update seek bar